# MariaDB auto increment problem

Tags: mysql

Using OpenSUSE leap 15.1
10.2.29-lp151.2.9.1-x86_64 from vendor OpenSUSE (installed)

```
CREATE TABLE testtab2(
    my_id2 INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name2 VARCHAR(10),
    comment2 VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (my_id2)
);
```

testtab.txt:

```
|Roger |hurray   |
|George|today    |
|Paul  |yesterday|
|John  |last year|
|Ringo |tomorrow |
```

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'testtab.txt' INTO TABLE testtab FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

works fine with linenumbers (my_id) 1-5

```
INSERT INTO testtab (name,comment) VALUES ('Beatles','band');
```

this gets linenumber (my_id) 8 - should be 6.

If testtab.txt have 8 records and using INSERT INTO 1 record this gets linenr (my_id) 16.
This happens in other tables too - one moved from 199 to 256.

Anyone who can solve the problem?

Comment: *works fine with linenumbers (my_id) 1-5* I don't believe. You MUST get ``Incorrect integer value: '' for column `db_name`.`testtab2`.`my_id2` at row 1``.

Comment: *should be 6.* No. Should be greater then maximal value which was inserted before. But don't have to be adjacent.

Comment: Other databases increment by 1 not a random above max value. This can not be correct.

Comment: You don't understand what is autoincrement field purpose, it seems. For example, in general nobody must access it (even select, and even more change) at all.

Comment: Got it here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment/  - Thanks!

Comment: What I must got there? Show me the words which tells that the generated values are strictly adjacent...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem, but expected, [documented behaviour](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment/):

> An `AUTO_INCREMENT` column normally has missing values. This happens because if a row is deleted, or an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is explicitly updated, old values are never re-used. [...] With InnoDB, values can be reserved by a transaction; but if the transaction fails (for example, because of a `ROLLBACK`) the reserved value will be lost.
>
> Thus `AUTO_INCREMENT` values can be used to sort results in a chronological order, but not to create a numeric sequence.

Most RDBMSes work this way. The identity/sequence/autoincrement value is not incremented by a random number. What happens is each session reserves and caches a certain, often configurable, number of identity/sequence/autoincrement values, and unused values from the cache are discarded if the session ends before they are all exhausted.

For example, session A reserves values 1 through 5 for itself, then session B reserves 6 to 10. Session A uses values 1, 2, and 3 and terminates, so 4 and 5 are never used.

If for some reason you require a gapless sequence (which in reality is very rarely needed), you'll have to implement it yourself, but note that this will be a performance bottleneck under any nontrivial workload.

Comment: This looks funny for me. 
Some years without using DB, but last time this was autoincrementing by 1. Standards obviously has changed as I see other DB do the same.
Why on earth jumping over numbers? The system should find max number and add 1, not a random number bigger then max number.
This even if some records are deleted.
Not useful to use auto-increment any more for creating primary key.
One have to do it manually anyway.  Thanks!

Comment: As I said, generating strictly consecutive keys 1) is almost never necessary and 2) always presents a serious concurrency (=performance) problem. Each session caches a certain, often configurable, number of identity/sequence/autoincrement values, and unused values from the cache are discarded if the session ends before they are all exhausted.